# iPad camera to cloud

Tags: photos, camera, network

I'm looking for a *truly basic* app that takes photos with the built-in camera and uploads them somewhere in the cloud.

I stress *basic* because I need my photos to be easily programmatically reused without a lot of translation (glue code) on my part.  For example: a Media RSS feed with nothing but the photos themselves, or a WebDAV folder.

Comment: Your looking for Photo Stream on iCloud. Does exactly this. Alternatively you can use Instagram to take basic photos.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is the functionality of Photo Stream on iCloud. Requires iOS5 and Lion (or a recent Windows version) though.